# PHP Exit; does not work

Tags: php

I'm working on a client's server and am finding the strangest things..

```
echo 7;
```

does not output 7.

```
echo "hello";
```

outputs hello.

and the `exit;` command does not work.

He's running 5.2.13 and Apache 2.0 Handler and has the Zend handler installed...

Anyone have any clue what might be going on?

Comment: Since independently nothing is wrong with any of those statements, more context would help. My best guess from what you've said so far is that a parse error elsewhere on the page is preventing some commands from working.

Comment: What **does** `echo 7` output? `echo "hello"` should output `hello` (without any quotes around it). If you wanted to output the quotes, too, you have to use `echo "\"hello\""`. But `echo 7` should work just fine. Also, how did you test `exit`? It's possible that you expected it to run during a loop but the loop was never entered or similar. Try a simple test: `<?php exit; echo "test! =D"; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might sound stupid, but maybe phpinfo(); could give some hints?

Comment: No not stupid; that was the first place I went to. Just didn't see anything out of the ordinary... hmm. VD is probably right...

Comment: probably so, anyway, quite an weird sittuation... anything else not working?